# Find next matching <span> bookmarklet for Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome, css

I am using [OpenCppCoverage](https://opencppcoverage.codeplex.com/), which highlights executed and non-executed lines in green and red as illustrated here:

[image]

I would like a bookmarklet or extension that for each green or red line (marked by `<span style = "background-color:#fdd">` or `<span style = "background-color:#dfd">`) inserts, for instance, a pair of up and down arrows to take me to the previous and next spans, something like:

```
$.prev( "span" ).css( "background-color", "#dfd" );
$.next( "span" ).css( "background-color", "#dfd" );
```

Actually, I suspect it would be quicker to just write the code myself!